# Is there a simple, safe, and reliable way to comment out a line in zsh at the shell prompt?

Tags: zsh

I often type out a command and then realize I need to do something else first, and I don't want to have to remember it all and figure out all the arguments or type it all again later, so I usually put `#` at the beginning to save it in history to use in a minute or so.

Normally I have `setopt interactivecomments` enabled in my .zshrc, but sometimes I have to `sudo` to a shared account on certain servers to do certain things, and that is not necessarily set, so prepending `#` before a line may earn me the annoying response

```
zsh: command not found: #
```

No matter, one might think, just use `:`, but it's not that simple.

```
$ : do_thing "1" && do_thing "2" && do_thing "3"
```

That would execute `do_thing "2" && do_thing "3"`.  Maybe not a big deal in some cases but what about something like this?

```
$ : cd /some/deeply/nested/directory && rm -rf *
```

Most commands are not *so* harmful, but remember this is a case where I realized I have to do something else before I execute the command(s) I typed, so it's always a case where I don't want to execute it or them *yet*.

What is a reliable, fast, harmless, and easy way to save a command that's already been typed?

`echo` has the same problem as `:`, and seems much less elegant.

Grouping everything inside `{` and `}` or `(` and `)` seemed to me like it might work but neither of them did. They gave me

```
zsh: parse error near `}'
```

and

```
zsh: parse error near `)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [the `push-line` widget](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Line-Editor.html#index-push_002dline), bound to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> in `emacs` mode by default, which is intended for that very purpose.

That will put what you have typed so far on hold (on a queue, called the *buffer stack* in the zsh documentation), clear the editing buffer so you can type your other command. After that other command has terminated, the command you had *pushed* earlier will be recalled automatically into the editing buffer.

A maybe better widget (but which won't help in your case where you use `zsh` in contexts where you don't control the `~/.zshrc`) is `push-input` which pushes the whole *input* instead of only the current line¹. That's better when entering multi-line commands, commands continued after the `$PS2` prompt is issued.

```
bindkey '^Q' push-input
bindkey '^[q' push-input
```

Note that the pushed line or input can also be retrieved with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> (`get-line` widget).

---

Another approach that also works in other shells is to erase the line with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> in `emacs` mode or <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>d</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> in `vi` mode, which will then be stored in the killring.

You can recall it later with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> in `emacs` mode or <kbd>p</kbd>/<kbd>P</kbd> in `vi` command mode. In `emacs` mode, you can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to cycle through the elements of the *killring* (recall past cut / copied strings).

In `vi` mode, you can also store the commands in named registers like in `vi`: `"xdd` in vi command mode would delete the line and store it in the `x` register, and you can recall it later with `"xP`.

---

As a more direct answer to your question, to comment out some code (an and-or list) when `interactive_comments` is off, you could insert `for _()` (the short form of `for` loop, here looping over the empty list) or `if (())` (short form of `if`, here with an empty arithmetic expression resolving to 0) in front of it.

That would comment out a `foo && bar || baz` and-or list, but not the `bar` in `foo; bar` or `foo & bar` for instance.

That also assumes the text entered so  far is syntactically valid, so wouldn't work for unfinished code (like unfinished quoted text, for loop...).

Another approach, with the same caveat would be to insert `:||(` at the start and `)` at the end. That would comment out any valid code.

---

<sup>¹ technically, the current *editing buffer* which could still contain multiple lines if you entered newlines with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or had recalled a multi-line command from history or the buffer stack.</sup>

Comment: Super-thorough answer, and super-useful!  

Answer (score 1):

Although Stéphane's first suggestion (the push-line widget) is simpler and faster, and preferable in many situations, I've found that I can also prepend one of the following to my command:

```
return &&
```

or

```
return;
```

This may be better in cases where I know I will want to execute several commands before returning to executing the one I just typed, and I don't want to have to hit <kbd>option</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> (<kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>) several times over.  It's also much more memorable than `for _()` (a later suggestion).